# How to add id using dojo.query to search element

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to add id to a  element using dojo.query. I'm not sure if it's possible though. I trying to use the code below to add the id but it's not working.

```
dojo.query('div[style=""]').attr("id","main-body");

<div style="">
  content
</div>
```

If this is not possible, is there another way to do it? Using javascript or jquery? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of adding an id to an element is correct.

The code runs fine for me in Firefox 17 and Chrome 23 but I have an issue in IE9. I suspect you may have the same issue.

In IE9 the query `div[style=""]` returns no results. The funny thing is,it works fine in compatibility mode!

t seems that in **IE9** in **normal** mode if an HTML element has an inline **empty style** attribute, that attribute is **not** being preserved when the element is added to the DOM.

So a solution would be to use a different query to find the divs you want.
You could try to find the divs with an empty style attributes **OR** with no style attribute at all.

A query like this should work:

```
div[style=""], div:not([style])
```

Take a look at the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");//just for the innerHTML() function

        dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
            var nodeListByAttr = dojo.query('div[style=""], div:not([style])');
            alert('Search by attribute nodeList length:' + nodeListByAttr.length);
            nodeListByAttr.attr("id", "main-body");

            var nodeListByID = dojo.query('#main-body');
            alert('Search by id nodeList length:' + nodeListByID.length);
            nodeListByID.innerHTML('Content set after finding the element by ID');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

@Nikanos' answer covers the query issue, I would like to add, that any query returns an array of elements, in case of Dojo it is [`dojo/NodeList`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/NodeList.html).

The problem is you are about to assign the same `id` to multiple DOM nodes, especially with query containing `div:not([style])`. I recommend to use more specific query like *first `div` child of `body`*:

```
var nodes = dojo.query('body > div:first-child');    
nodes.attr("id", "main-body");
```

To make it more robust, do not manipulate all the nodes, just the first node (even through there should be just one):

```
dojo.query('body > div:first-child')[0].id = "main-body";
```

This work also in IE9, see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/JN4cz/

The same example written in [Modern Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/): http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/BReda/